# Is a proxy web server the same as a firewall application gateway?

Tags: networking, firewall, proxy

I need a clarification regarding proxy server.

Is a web proxy server (in this case installed on win server) the type of a firewall? I thought these two are different. I am currently learning about firewalls and I see that the author mentions application firewall gateway but actually describes a proxy server.

I know they are different in essence since they operate on different layers but this made me a bit confused. Is a proxy server really a type of a firewall?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Proxy is a relay that accepts a connection and makes its own connection on your behalf. Firewall is a rules based network security system.

Sophisticated [firewalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) likely include security aware proxies. Security oriented in that they understand application details like protocols, encryption such as TLS, and hopefully user identity.  And via proxy, as where else are you going to put it, other than a proxy middlebox?

But no, a proxy doesn't mean a firewall. These are broad categories of network services. Beware when making broad statements:

- Not all proxies are security oriented, some do other services like load balancing.
- Not every proxy is web, there are proxies for non-http protocols.
- Not every firewall is a layer 3 packet filter. Layer 4-ish knowledge is useful for connection tracking. Application level knowledge allows for smarter decisions than when limited to a TCP/IP 5-tuple.
- Not every firewall is application aware, either. Sometimes, a layer 4 packet filter is sufficient.